# How can I have a fixed size wastpaper basket?

Tags: macos, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to limit the size of the Trash?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9583/is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-size-of-the-trash)

I'd like to have a way to auto-deleted item in the basket, based upon the time they come in (oldest to be deleted first)...

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this with a Folder Action. 
[apple.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/folder-actions-tutorial-automation-meet-the-filesystem/](http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/folder-actions-tutorial-automation-meet-the-filesystem/)

when new item is added, count items in folder, if number of items is greater than threshhold, delete oldest one.

This requires some knowledge of how the trash works...Something about the .Trashes hidden folders.

Comment: Does anyone know a way to get the times files were moved to the trash? Something like this isn't really feasible if it's based on modification dates.

Comment: You could change the modified time when items are moved to trash with a simple call to 'touch' in a [bash script](http://www.macworld.com/article/1151498/sort_downloads.html).